# Why DATEDIFF in SQL Server returning error while interval is set to second

Tags: sql-server, datediff

While running following query

```
select DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, DATEADD(SECOND, -1, '2014-04-11 23:52'))
```

I am getting following error message, no matter whatever the date I provide to it.

> The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

Comment: your first arguement for DATEDIFF needs to be a DATETIME value not integer value.

Comment: What were you trying to do with this? Because `0` is interpreted as 1st Jan 1900 and there have been more than 31 billion seconds since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datediff takes these parameters: interval, starting_date, ending_date, so your SELECT is trying to find difference in seconds between server default for starting_date and your date.
When you specified 0 as starting_date, MS SQL replaced it with '1900-01-01 00:00'. The returned seconds where ~3606249060, but the DATEDIFF returns int, and the seconds returned where larger than datatype int could handle.

It works fine if you specify `minute` instead of `second`, because it'll return 60104151, which is int

You could use similar select to find difference in seconds between now and your defined date:

```
select DATEDIFF(SECOND, GETDATE(), DATEADD(SECOND,-1,'2014-04-11 23:52'))
```

If you put your hard-coded date as starting_date parameter, then you'll get -1 second difference (due to DATEADD you've used):

```
select DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2014-04-11 23:52', DATEADD(SECOND,-1,'2014-04-11 23:52'))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) DateDiff is not working because difference between 2 dates in Interval of Seconds is more than 68 years.

First argument in DateDiff as 0 means it is '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', and difference with '2014-04-11 23:52' is more than 68 years.

Answer (score 0):

Your current query results in a bigint, DATEDIFF can only return an integer. That is why you get overflow

3597523200 is the seconds between year 1900 and 2014

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 3597523200 
   + DATEDIFF(S, '2014', DATEADD(SECOND,-1,'2014-04-11 23:52'))
```

This would be the same as:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(S, '1900', '1950') AS BIGINT) 
   + DATEDIFF(S, '1950', '2014')
   + DATEDIFF(S, '2014', DATEADD(SECOND,-1,'2014-04-11 23:52'))
```